# LSTM Model; Invalid input_h shape: [1,10,128] [1,4,128]

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

So I'm trying to create a phoneme classifier using an LSTM (CuDNNLSTM) via Keras. The problem is everytime I try to train my model I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Invalid input_h shape: [1,10,128] [1,4,128]
     [[node sequential_11/cu_dnnlstm_33/CudnnRNNV2 (defined at <ipython-input-26-8a407dd29428>:47) ]] [Op:__inference_test_function_71890]
```

This is the shape of my dataset:

```
x_train.shape= (10, 100, 16)
y_train.shape= (10, 100)
x_test.shape= (6, 100, 16)
y_test.shape= (6, 100)
x_validation.shape= (4, 100, 16)
y_validation.shape= (4, 100)
```

Each y label corresponds to a vector of 16 floats.

This is my `build_model` function

```
def build_model(input_shape=None, LR=.001, phone_count=61):
  
  #build the network
  model= Sequential()
  #RNN layer 1
  model.add(CuDNNLSTM(128, batch_input_shape=(input_shape), return_sequences=True))
  model.add(Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  
  #RNN layer 2
  model.add(CuDNNLSTM(128, input_shape=(input_shape), return_sequences=True))
  model.add(Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  
  #RNN layer 3
  model.add(CuDNNLSTM(128, input_shape=(input_shape), return_sequences=True))
  model.add(Dropout(0.2))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  
  
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
  model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))

  #softmax layer
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(phone_count, activation='softmax'))

  #compile the model
  the_optimizer= keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LR)
  model.compile(optimizer=the_optimizer, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
  # model.compile(optimizer=the_optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

  model.summary()

  return model
```

And this is the summary of my model:

```
Model: "sequential_11"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
cu_dnnlstm_33 (CuDNNLSTM)    (10, 100, 128)            74752     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_44 (Dropout)         (10, 100, 128)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_33 (Batc (10, 100, 128)            512       
_________________________________________________________________
cu_dnnlstm_34 (CuDNNLSTM)    (10, 100, 128)            132096    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_45 (Dropout)         (10, 100, 128)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_34 (Batc (10, 100, 128)            512       
_________________________________________________________________
cu_dnnlstm_35 (CuDNNLSTM)    (10, 100, 128)            132096    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_46 (Dropout)         (10, 100, 128)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_35 (Batc (10, 100, 128)            512       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_22 (Dense)             (10, 100, 32)             4128      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_47 (Dropout)         (10, 100, 32)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_23 (Dense)             (10, 100, 61)             2013      
=================================================================
Total params: 346,621
Trainable params: 345,853
Non-trainable params: 768
_________________________________________________________________
```

This is my main  function

```
x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, x_validation, y_validation= prep_data(Temp=True)


for i in range(y_train.__len__()):
  y_train[i]=y_train[i][0:100]
  x_train[i]=x_train[i][0:100]
  x_train[i]= np.array(x_train[i])
  y_train[i]= np.array(y_train[i])
for i in range(y_test.__len__()):
  y_test[i]=y_test[i][0:100]
  x_test[i]=x_test[i][0:100]
  x_test[i]= np.array(x_test[i])
  y_test[i]= np.array(y_test[i])
for i in range(y_validation.__len__()):
  y_validation[i]=y_validation[i][0:100]
  x_validation[i]=x_validation[i][0:100]
  x_validation[i]= np.array(x_validation[i])
  y_validation[i]= np.array(y_validation[i])

x_train= np.array(x_train)
y_train= np.array(y_train)
x_test= np.array(x_test)
y_test= np.array(y_test)
x_validation= np.array(x_validation)
y_validation= np.array(y_validation)

model= build_model(input_shape, phone_count=61)

#train the model  
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=40, batch_size=10, validation_data=(x_validation, y_validation))  
# model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=40, batch_size=1, validation_split=0.2)  

#evaluate the model
error, accuracy= model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print(f"Test error: {error}, Test accuracy: {accuracy}")
```

The problem occurs when I try to train the model (`model_fit`). If I change the batch number in `model_fit`  to `1` the model trains successfully, but a similar error `Invalid input_h shape: [1,10,128] [1,6,128]` occurs when I try to evaluate the model at line `error, accuracy= model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)`. The shapes of my data seem to be consistent with each other as well my parameters so I don't see the problem. If anyone has any idea please let me know.

Comment: what are you passing as `batch_input_shape` ?

Comment: @MichaelJanz the shape of my training data ```(10, 100, 16)```. I'll add my main function to make it easier to see.

Answer (score 0):

So one error I see is that your input_shape=(10,100,16) indicates, that your model expects 100 timesteps with 16 values each. But your first layer has 128 neurons. Either you want to add a `Input_Layer` or reduce the number of neurons in your first layer down to 16, as you have 16 features per timestep